# How do i resolve this error? It seems that updating to v21 is giving the error and couldn't find any solution

Tags: android, eclipse

\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the `project.properties` file, open it and set target to 21

```
target=android-21
```